# Extracting CNF representation of my problem from SAT solver

Tags: cplex, solver, constraint-programming, or-tools, sat

As I know, any SAT solver such as or-tools or cplex cp optimizer converts a given problem to CNF form in the first place. Is it possible to extract the resulting CNF representation from or-tools or cplex?

Comment: CPLEX CPO is not a SAT solver but a CP solver. To our knowledge, it does not convert the given model to CNF form. Google OR Tools CP-SAT solver is not a pure SAT solver as well. Roughly speaking, this is a CP solver that embeds SAT techniques as subroutines. The model is given following a CP formalism.

Answer (score 5):

CP-SAT uses a SAT backend.  But at any moment, just like with SMT solvers, the full model is never fully represented using clauses and Boolean literals. I recommend looking at the CPAIOR 2020 masterclass on CP (on YouTube) to get a better understanding of the architecture of the solver.

Answer (score 3):

Quick hack

- Get glpk sources
- Edit src/api/minisat1.c
- Find

```
int glp_minisat1(glp_prob *P)
{     /* solve CNF-SAT problem with MiniSat solver */
      solver *s;
      GLPAIJ *aij;
```

- Add one line

```
int glp_minisat1(glp_prob *P)
{     /* solve CNF-SAT problem with MiniSat solver */
      glp_write_cnfsat(P, "tmptmp.cnf");
      solver *s;
      GLPAIJ *aij;
```

- Compile

./configure && make

- Run

examples/glpsol --lp prob.lp --minisat

- Quit solving with ctrl-c

Now you have tmptmp.cnf in the same directory.