# Does a modeling language that generates SAT instances exist?

Tags: modeling-languages, sat

Nowadays, we enjoy the expressivity of modern modeling languages.  However, does it exists a modeling language  that takes in input a declarative problem definition (like [AMPL](https://ampl.com/) or [MiniZinc](https://www.minizinc.org/), or similar), and produces as output a SAT instance, for instance in the [DIMACS format](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/data/cnf/cnf.html), which can be later solved with any SAT solver which support a standard format?

This is for achieving something similar to what we do using the *.mps* or *.lp* format for ILP problems.

**NOTE:** This question is related to this other (but it is not exactly the same):
[Extracting CNF representation of my problem from SAT solver](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6579/extracting-cnf-representation-of-my-problem-from-sat-solver)

Comment: I guess [Picat/PicatSAT](http://picat-lang.org/download/cp19_tutorial.pdf) (or all those other CSP to SAT converters: page 6) somewhat do this, although i never looked into those. I'm also not fully sure how to interpret the question as *DIMACS CNF* is the SAT-equivalent of *LP/MPS* files in MP to me: low-lvl instance-definitions. Both variants imho already passed the modelling layer (e.g. core decisions like cardinality-encoding in SAT; compact vs. non-compact encodings in MP) and some solvers even try to reconstruct *now lost information* again (e.g. cardinality constraints in SAT).

Comment: Thanks @sascha, I will look into the tutorial! Regarding the DIMACS CNF format, the question is related to the possibility of writing the encoding of an instance once and then reusing it easily with different SAT solvers: a fast way of comparing SAT solvers on instances of my interest.

Comment: A friend has suggested an interesting answer on another stack-site: [How can I express scheduling problems in-MiniSat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27507206/how-can-i-express-scheduling-problems-in-minisat)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the @hakank answer is pretty nice and useful, I found exactly what I was looking for:

> [PySAT, SAT Technology in Python](https://pysathq.github.io/)

With PySAT, via the [PyPBLIB](https://pypi.org/project/pypblib/), it is possible to write high-level pseudo-boolean formulas (e.g., `at-least-k`,`at-most-k`,`at-exactly-k`, $\sum_{i \in I} a_i x_i \leq b$, ...), and then to get the global CNF formula, which can be dumped in a standard [DIMACS SAT file](http://www.domagoj-babic.com/uploads/ResearchProjects/Spear/dimacs-cnf.pdf).

Moreover, you can easily switch from one  SAT solver to another.
The list of [SAT solvers available via PySAT](https://pysathq.github.io/docs/html/api/solvers.html) is in the online documentation.

What is very nice, is that you can experiment with the different encoding of the same constraint, like *binary decision diagrams (BDD)*, *sequential weight counters*, *sorting networks*, *adder networks*, ... you can find even more encoding in the [documentation](https://pysathq.github.io/docs/html/api/pb.html#module-details).

And (*YES!*) the fact that is accessible via Python is a plus.

Answer (score 5):

As @sascha mentions, Picat has the option to save a SAT model to CNF, using the `dump(file.cnf)` option (or just `dump` to print the CNF to stdout). It's described a little more in the Picat Guide  section 12.6.3 "Solving Options for sat" (See http://picat-lang.org/download/picat_guide.pdf)

Here's a small example how to use this for a Picat model:

```
import sat.

main => queens(8,Q).

queens(N, Q) =>
    Q=new_list(N),
    Q :: 1..N,
    all_different(Q),
    all_different($[Q[I]-I : I in 1..N]),
    all_different($[Q[I]+I : I in 1..N]),

    solve($[dump("sat_dump.cnf"),ff],Q).
```

The output file `sat_dump.cnf` then contains the CNF for this model. Note that when using the `dump/1` option, the model don't solves the problem, it just creates the CNF file.

With a little tweaking one can use this to generate CNF for a MiniZinc model  using the PicatSAT program, see https://github.com/nfzhou/fzn_picat/ . The fix is to add the option `dump(file.cnf)` to the options (`Option = ...` ) in the file `fzn_picat_sat.pi` . Note that with this simple fix, after the program generated the CNF file, there will probably be an error when the program tries to print out the solution (since there is no created solution that can be printed).

Comment: Thanks @hakank! I wait a few days to see if another answer appears, otherwise I will accept your answer.

Comment: @StefanoGualandi Great! Please take your time, it's no hurry.

Comment: Please change `,` to `.` in the line `queens(8,Q).`

Comment: @agershun: Thanks for catching that.